# ASP.NET user database without web.config connection strings

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, web-config, membership-provider

I'm wondering whether it's possible to use built in ASP.NET application services (aspnet_user, aspnet_role etc table) without specifying a connection string in a web.config.

At the moment I store connection strings externally, but I keep finding hard-coded connection strings all over the web.config xml, various providers etc. It's driving me crazy.

Thank you

Comment: Just a note: the concepts "hard-coded" and "data in a web.config" are mutually exclusive.  Hard-Coded means that the information is stored inside the actual code, requiring a recompile to change.  Putting data in a config file is the way to avoid "hard coding" information.  Just semantics ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll rephrase myself. What I was trying to say is that I don't like the application services adding connection strings into various config files "automatically".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own provider via overriding already existed, built-in class so it will read it's connection string from somewhere else:

```
public class MyMembershiProvider : SqlMembershiProvider
{
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        config["connectionString"] = "what ever you want";

        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, 

thank you for this. This still means that application will look for different configuration files depending whether it's a web.config it's after or app.config. On top of this I have unit tests which seem to be using a conncetion string of their own. LINQ to SQL had connection strings built in some configuration files - I removed those. At the moment my main concern is asp net data providers.

Comment: @vikp: So you want to minimize the number of connection strings used in the application? You can specify not `connectionString` but `connectionStringName` so it will read it appropriate connection string from Web.config/connectionStrings node. Рад помочь! :)

Comment: @vikp: Also you can use special class to hold (manage) your connection string(s). I do so. `public static class Database { public static SqlConnection GetConnection() { } }` which holds your connection string(s) or reads them from Web.config or anywhere else

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Was away. Yes I'd like to minimise the number of places where I store the connection strings. I'm not too keen on web.config or app.config. In my opinion too many things are done for you behind the scenes, which I don't like. I will use a helper class which will read the connection strings from encrypted XML config. Hopefully overhead of reading data from encrypted xml config file won't be too big. Thanks a lot!