# connect to database without web.config file

Tags: c#

I have a project that is NOT a website project, so there is no web.config file.
I want to connect to my database. How can I do this when I don't have the web.config file to tell the database name, url, password etc?

By searching I found this: [ASP.NET user database without web.config connection strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064787/asp-net-user-database-without-web-config-connection-strings)

But I don't know if this is what I need. I didn't experience from it anyway.
Thanks

Ps. It is a wpf project.

Comment: What do you exactly want to connect ?

Comment: AFAIK, you can define the connection string details _on the fly_.

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Then what kind of project *is it*?  Presumably any .NET application is going to have a config file available to it.  If there's truly no config file at all then you can hard-code your connection string.  Or perhaps fetch it manually from some external resource such as a text file or XML file (which is basically manually replicating the functionality of a config file).

Comment: Alex, I don't see why you needd code for this?

Comment: How are we meant to help you if we can't see the exact issue you're having... Please read up on how to ask questions on SO

Answer (score 4):

By the following way, you can define connection strings to connect with database without using web.config file.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master;");
```

Comment: @user3899302 - looks like you've only upvoted this. At least mark this as the answer if its what you needed (click the tick next to the up / down arrows).

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a Web application, you should have an `app.config` that will work the same way.